# What should be the alternative for lead and lag for SQL Server 2000 to 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

What could be the alternative for `lead` and `lag` for SQL Server 2000 to 2008? I am trying to get previous and next invoice number to given invoice number, 
i.e 5

```
SqlDataAdapter invoiceAdptr = new SqlDataAdapter(@"
                 select t.prev_invNo, t.InvNo, t.next_invNo
                 from (select 
                           lag(InvNo) over (order by id) as prev_invNo,
                           InvNo,
                           lead(InvNo) over (order by id) as next_invNo
                       from Invoice1) t
                 where t.InvNo = " + invoiceNumber + "", con);

DataTable invoiceDataTable = new DataTable();
invoiceAdptr.Fill(invoiceDataTable);

var invoices = new Invoices()
{
    PreviousInvoice = Convert.ToString(invoiceDataTable.Rows[0]["prev_invNo"]),
    NextInvoice = Convert.ToString(invoiceDataTable.Rows[0]["next_invNo"]),
    CurrentInvoice = invoiceNumber
};
```

Comment: It is now 2017. Time to upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me

```
"WITH CTE AS(
                       SELECT rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY p.InvNo),
                       p.InvNo FROM Invoice1 p
                     )
                   SELECT
                   prev.InvNo prev_invNo,
                       CTE.InvNo,
                       nex.InvNo next_invNo
                   FROM CTE
                   LEFT JOIN CTE prev ON prev.rownum = CTE.rownum - 1
                   LEFT JOIN CTE nex ON nex.rownum = CTE.rownum + 1
                   where CTE.InvNo = " + invoiceNumber + ""
```

Comment: I strongly recommend the approach using `apply`, because it can make better use of indexes.

Answer (score 4):

Use `outer apply` in SQL 2005-2008:

```
select ilag.InvNo as prev_invNo,
       InvNo,
       ilead.InvNo as next_invNo
from Invoice1 i outer apply
     (select top 1 i2.*
      from Invoice1 i2
      where i2.id < i.id
      order by id2.id desc
     ) ilag outer apply
     (select top 1 i2.*
      from Invoice1 i2
      where i2.id > i.id
      order by id2.id asc
     ) ilead 
where t.InvNo = " + invoiceNumber + "";
```

Note that the subquery is no longer needed.  However, this is generally much less efficient than the `lag()` and `lead()` functions.

Don't use SQL Server 2000.  It hasn't been supported for years.  (You can modify the above to be subqueries if you really want to use unsupported software.)

Comment: Congratulations on 500K!  A well deserved achievement.  Just curious, was there a balloon drop?.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone can't upgrade... for Sql Server 2000 you can use subqueries:

```
select
      InvNo
    , prev_invNo = (
        select top 1 invNo 
        from invoices p 
        where p.id < i.id 
        order by id desc
        )
    , next_invNo = (
        select top 1 invNo 
        from invoices n 
        where n.id > i.id 
        order by id asc
        )
  from Invoice1 as i
```